# Custom control - data binding not working

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am currently trying to extend a `sap.m.Input` field to be able to style and extend the label placement. 
The rendering works fine, but somehow the data-binding gets lost in the process and i am unsure why that is. This is my control:

```
sap.ui.define([
  'sap/m/Input',
], function(Input) {
  'use strict';

  return Input.extend('one.sj.control.BhTextInput', {
    metadata: {
      properties: {
        label: {
          type: 'string',
        },
      },
      aggregations: {
          icon: {
            type: 'sap.ui.core.Icon',
            multiple: false,
            visibility: 'public',
          },
      },
    },

    renderer: function(oRM, oControl) {
      oRM.write('<div class="formControl">');

      oRM.write('<input placeholder="'+oControl.getPlaceholder()+'"');
      oRM.write('type="'+oControl.getType()+'"');
      oRM.write('value="'+oControl.getValue()+'"');
      oRM.writeClasses();
      oRM.writeControlData(oControl);
      oRM.write('/>');
      oRM.write('<label class="inputLabel" for="'+oControl.getId()+'"');
      oRM.write('>');
      oRM.renderControl(oControl.getIcon());
      oRM.write('<span class="inputLabelContent">');
      oRM.write(oControl.getLabel());
      oRM.write('</span>');
      oRM.write('</label>');

      oRM.write('</div>');
    },
  });
});
```

As you can see it is quite simple. 
This is how i use it:

```
<sj:BhTextInput
    id="username" class="input textInput"
    placeholder="{i18n>HINT_USERNAME}" value="{creds>/username}"
    type="Text">
  <sj:icon>
    <core:Icon src="sap-icon://email" class="inputIcon" />
  </sj:icon>
</sj:BhTextInput>
```

I confirmed that is not a problem of my model, as it works fine when i replace the manual `<input/>` construction in the `renderer` method above with:

```
sap.m.InputRenderer.render(oRM, oControl);
```

Can you spot anything wrong? Thanks!

**EDIT:** To clarify a bit on what i mean by "data-binding gets lost". I am only getting an empty string when accessing the value bound to the Input field inside my controller like this: `getModel('creds').getProperty('/username');`. This does work when replacing the manual construction as written above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what causing your problem but I believe oRM.write doesn't add spaces to your rendered HTML. It is better to use oRM.writeAttribute for writing attributes. Also class should be added using oRM.addClass.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know about writeAttribute. Sadly this does not change anything. My current solution is just to use the InputRenderer. I believe that because the Input is not actually rendered that also the onAfterRendering of the Input is not called which might be were some of the binding happens.

Comment: Maybe you could share your generated HTML tags?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. There are couple of changes that are required to get it working.

Note 1: The InputBase API ( parent of sap.m.Input) needs your `<input>` tag to have an id containing `"inner"` to fetch its value properly. This is from INputBase API:

`/**
     * Returns the DOM value respect to maxLength
     * When parameter is set chops the given parameter
     *
     * TODO: write two different functions for two different behaviour
     */`

```
InputBase.prototype._getInputValue = function(sValue) {
        sValue = (sValue === undefined) ? this.$("inner").val() || "" : sValue.toString();

        if (this.getMaxLength && this.getMaxLength() > 0) {
            sValue = sValue.substring(0, this.getMaxLength());
        }

        return sValue;
    };
```

So, on every change, it reads the DOM value and then updates the control metadata.

`/**
     * Handles the change event.
     *
     * @protected
     * @param {object} oEvent
     * @returns {true|undefined} true when change event is fired
     */`

```
InputBase.prototype.onChange = function(oEvent) {

    // check the control is editable or not
    if (!this.getEditable() || !this.getEnabled()) {
        return;
    }

    // get the dom value respect to max length
    var sValue = this._getInputValue();

    // compare with the old known value
    if (sValue !== this._lastValue) {

        // save the value on change
        this.setValue(sValue);

        if (oEvent) {
        //IE10+ fires Input event when Non-ASCII characters are used. As this is a real change
        // event shouldn't be ignored.
            this._bIgnoreNextInputEventNonASCII = false;
        }


        // get the value back maybe formatted
        sValue = this.getValue();

        // remember the last value on change
        this._lastValue = sValue;

        // fire change event
        this.fireChangeEvent(sValue);

        // inform change detection
        return true;
    } else {
        // same value as before --> ignore Dom update
        this._bCheckDomValue = false;
    }
};
```

So, I changed your renderer method of the control like this:

```
renderer: function(oRM, oControl) {
      oRM.write('<div class=formControl');
      oRM.writeClasses();
      oRM.writeControlData(oControl); // let div handle control metadata such as id.
      oRM.write(">")
      oRM.write('<input placeholder="'+oControl.getPlaceholder()+'"');
      oRM.write('id="'+oControl.getId()+'-inner"'); // set id with 'inner' 
//      oRM.write('type="'+oControl.getType()+'"'); dont know why type is throwing error s=, so had to comment it.
      oRM.write('value="'+oControl.getMyValue()+'"');
//      oRM.writeClasses();
//      oRM.writeControlData(oControl);
      oRM.write('/>');
      oRM.write('<label class="inputLabel" for="'+oControl.getId()+'"');
      oRM.write('>');
      oRM.renderControl(oControl.getIcon());
      oRM.write('<span class="inputLabelContent">');
      oRM.write(oControl.getLabel());
      oRM.write('</span>');
      oRM.write('</label>');

      oRM.write('</div>');
}
```

Let me know if this works for you. :)